# Large (natural) numbers in Java

Tags: java, performance

Let's assume that we have Oracle DB with column NUMBER(38,0). Basically it is an ID which is generated by DB. What is the best way to handle it in Java? It is only read and compared. JMC shows that a lot of time is spent on comparing these values (almost 7% time spent on compareTo). I tried to cast them into String and then compare strings (it is 3xfaster). 
Is there any other, better way to speed that up?

EDIT.
The values are compared only to check if they are equal. It's not my code and I have no idea why equals is not used...

Comment: Could you please show us your code that compares the values? How *large* are the numbers? Can't you take `long` or `Long` for it? Try `BigInteger` as well.

Comment: In your method with Strings did you add all the leading zeros to numbers? Without leading zeros comparison will be incorrect - e.g. 110 will be lower than 12.

Comment: @deHaar Well, I thought NUMBER(38,0) is enough. It can have 38 digits, thus long will not work.

Comment: Where do you call / set / use `NUMBER(38,0)`? In Java or in SQL?

Comment: @deHaar "OracleDB with column NUMBER(38,0)" = I have a Oracle Database in which there is a column with data type NUMBER(38,0). Now it is just mapped into BigDecimal without any specific annotations.

Comment: And does `BigDecimal` work in a performant way or is that the approach that is slower than the `String` approach? According to [this mapping overview](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14188/datamap.htm), the mapping to `BigDecimal` seems desired (by Oracle or JDBC developers).

Comment: Just a note to your edit: When working with `BigDecimal`, the `equals` method doesnt only check for equal numbers, but also for precision. That's why you have to use `compareTo(other) == 0` to check for equal numbers when using `BigDecimal`.

`new BigDecimal(1, 1).equals(new BigDecimal(1, 0))` is `false`

Comment: @deHaar I used micro benchamark and it shows that value1.toString().compareTo(value2.toString()) is three times faster than value1.compareTo(value2()). I know it could be a bit different in production code, but I think that big difference can not be just "newbie" benchmarking.

Comment: @codeflush.dev Yeah, I know that, but since all values are mapped from same column, their precision and scale should be the same. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Then just use the `String` comparison and make sure you are controlling what @Amongalen wrote in his comment. Remember the conversion to have influence on performance, too.

Comment: Try using `to_char(<your_column>)` in your SQL, retrieve the value as a String in your application and compare them. That should be even faster than reading a `BigDecimal` first and then converting it to a string.

Comment: Can you please **show** relevant code? Thanks.